# messages.includes is not a function javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check if a  string from an array exists in another array. "data", the parameter of function is an array containing messages. But I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: messages.includes is not a function". Is there any solution to this? Thanks in advance.

```
   socket.on('show_all_messages', function(data) {
     // console.log(data);
     var messages = document.getElementById('messages').children;
      len = data.length;
      for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if(!(messages.includes(data[i])))
              {
              const newNode = document.createElement('div');
              newNode.innerHTML = data[i];
              document.getElementById('messages').appendChild(newNode);
            }
        } 

    })
```

Comment: `includes` is a function on an Array object but `messages` is not an Array.

Comment: What's the solution then?

Answer (score 0):

The `messages` object comes from using `.children` which returns an `HTMLCollection` not an `Array` so there is no `includes` function.

I presume  you want to search the text of each child element for matches in the `data` array. So I assume your html looks something like this:

```
<div id='messages'>
  <span>Some text</span>
  <span>More text</span>
  <span>Other stuff</span>
</div>
```

If that's right and you want to search each string in the child elements (the spans) for any string in the `data` array you could do something like this:

```
for (let i=0; i<messages.length; i++) {
  if (messages[i].textContent && 
      messages[i].textContent.indexOf(data[i]) >= 0) {
    const newNode = document.createElement('div');
    newNode.innerHTML = data[i];
    document.getElementById('messages').appendChild(newNode);
  }
}
```

But that will result in new `<div>` nodes added within the outer element. Is that what you want?

Comment: No sorry, not exactly. But I think the main problem is that "var messages = document.getElementById('messages').children;" Do you have any alternate ideas to save child elements of a div into a array?

Comment: Can you show the structure of the html in your question?